# Неверная кодировка при заполнении Combobox из БД C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, база-данных, mysql-workbench

Есть такой код для заполнения Combobox из таблицы БД

```
public static void forComboBox(string field, string table, ComboBox cb)
    {
        string query = "Select " + field + " from " + table;
        DataSet ds = queryToData(query);

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables["Table"].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cb.Items.Add(ds.Tables["Table"].Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Вызываю его так:

```
DBHelp.forComboBox("fio", "sotrudniki", comboBox1);
```

Но тут проблема в том, что фамилии, написанные на русском, он выводит какими-то иероглифами в сам комбобокс. В самой БД кодировку менял и на ut8_general_ci, и на cp1251, но толку нет. Английские буквы отображает нормально. При этом, запись в самой БД отображается нормально.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation')); какой результат на БД?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin В Воркбенче, если исполнять это как скрипт, выдает ошибку "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'))' at line 1"

Comment: Ага, почитайте описание метки sql-server, особенно внимательно эту часть: Не используйте тег для других систем управления базами данных: MySQL, PostgreSQL и др.

Comment: Совет: используйте привязку данных: `cb.DisplayMember = field; cb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`. Цикл `for` после этого не нужен. А ещё избавьтесь от `DataSet`, оставьте только `DataTable`.